# javapackager OSX code sign fail

Tags: java, macos, code-signing, javapackager

I have a Java app that I wish to distribute through the App store: there seems to be a problem signing the app. I am using JDK 1.8.0_77, JavaPackager 8.0 and OSX 10.11.4.

As I understand it, Oracle and Apple are playing cat and mouse (not sure who the cat is though) and Apple have withdrawn appBundler. According to [this page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/packagingAppsForMac.html), an independent group have taken over support of [appbundler](https://java.net/projects/appbundler), but the links from this page with instructions for submission to  the Apple site no longer work. Furthermore, there has been no activity on the appBundler project for three years, so I assume that it's no longer relevant.

I am therefore using javapackager, using the instructions from [this page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/javapackager.html). here is my script:

```
$jdk/bin/javapackager 
-deploy 
-native mac.appStore 
-srcfiles issue/myApp.jar 
-appclass myApp.myAppName -name myAppname -outdir app 
-outfile myAppName.app -Bmac.category=Education 
-Bmac.CFBundleIdentifier=com.myDomain.myAppName 
-Bmac.CFBundleName=myAppName 
-Bmac.CFBundleVersion=2.0 
-Bmac.signing-key-developer-id-app="3rd Party Mac Developer Application: J Latte (XYZ1234ABC)" 
-Bmac.bundle-id-signing-prefix=XYZ1234ABC
-v
```

javapackager code signs all of the individual items in the build, but fails when it attempts to sign the app:

```
Running [codesign, 
-s, 3rd Party Mac Developer Application: J Latte (XYZ1234ABC), 
-vvvv, 
--entitlements, /var/.../macosx/myAppName.entitlements, 
/var/.../images/image-6308255237594199313/myAppName.app]
/var/...images/image-6308255237594199313/myAppName.app: 
code object is not signed at all
```

I would welcome any suggestions for ways out of this hole.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I had to remove all certificates from the AppStore in the Keychain and redownload them. Every last one of them.